# load exteral form into html div and try to on submit with validation but its not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

onclick =id(myModalssid) used to call the html(external_form_fields.html .formval) file in particular into div(.modal-body-id). that div contain form, i need validation of the form in on submit.

```
<script>
    $('#myModalssid').click(function ()
       {
         $('.modal-body-id').load('external_form_fields.html .from_val');
         alert('Message');
       });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create function in jQuery for validation,

And call that function in your click event...

Just like:--

```
<script>
    $('#myModalssid').click(function () {
        $('.modal-body-id').load('external_form_fields.html .from_val');
        alert('dgfdfgs');
        formValidation();
    });
    function formValidation()
    {
         //Your validation Process...
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i have a external js script. how do i use to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the validation script when the form is loaded:

```
$('#myModalssid').click(function ()
   {
     $('.modal-body-id').load('external_form_fields.html .from_val', function() {
         $('.form').on('submit', function() {
             //your validation script
         });
     });

   });
```

Comment: i have a external js script. how do i use to validate it.